# React Native persisting user data

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, async-await, react-native

In my app I have 2 components (`Page` and `Home`).

`Home` extends `Page` like so:

`export default class Home extends Page`

and `Page` just extends `Component`.

In `Page` I have a method to get user data from `AsyncStorage`

```
async getUser() {
  // get from storage
  this.setState({user});
}
```

The above is called on the `constructor` of `Page`.

The problem I have is that `Home` has a method on `componentWillMount` that relies on `this.state.user`. Obviously this isn't going to work since the `getUser` method is async.

Is there a way I can get the user information and only call specific methods once I have that info?

```
export default class Page extends Component {
  async getUser() {
    // get from AsyncStorage
    this.setState({user});
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }
}

export default class Home extends Page {
  async foo(user_id) {
    this.setState({something});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.foo(this.state.user);
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>{this.state.something}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: What method relies on `this.state.user` and when is it called?

Comment: There is another async method on `Home.componentWillMount` that relies on `this.state.user`

Comment: I've updated  the question with example code

Comment: I know this isn't the most elegant option but, you can can execute some method after fetch user in page, like `page.onUserUpdate`, and you can override this method at Home or other page subclass. Other option is to define some default value for user until this value be ready to render on screen, this approach allow you to for example, display some kind of loading user process in UI.

Comment: Can you call the getUser inside your Home component?

    componentWillMount() {
        super.getUser.then(this.foo)
    }

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can get the user information and only call specific
>   methods once I have that info?

Not in a general sense, but of course there are some solutions. What this comes down to is that you have an async data dependency. You need to write the code in such a way that a call to dependent functions is only made after the data becomes available.

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to use [`componentWillUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate) instead of `componentDidMount` and check if you are receiving the required data:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.user != null && this.state.user !== nextState.user) {
        this.prepareForUser(nextState.user);
    }
}
```

(Note that you can't `setState` directly in `componentWillUpdate`, but since your method is async it won't happen until later. You can use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) to chain another `setState` call.)

Another option (which I like to use) is to use composition instead of inheritance. This makes the life-cycle easier to control through rendering: the parent can only `render` a child when all the child's dependent data is loaded, then the child does not need to worry about any timing issues related to the initial loading of data and can do whatever it wants from its `componentDidMount`:

```
class UserContainer extends Component {
    state = {};
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUser();
    }
    async getUser() {
        // get user from async store
        this.setState({user});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.user ? <UserView user={this.state.user} /> : <Spinner /> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class UserView extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.user != null
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the ["container component"](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.7os7km3n3) pattern.